# Visual help to understand epi-convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have read the definition of epi-convergence in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epi-convergence), but would like to get a sense of definition by some visual example (or at least easy to understand functions). Any help?

Comment: Isn't epi-convergence the same definition of [gamma-convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%93-convergence)? If it is so, the examples on Section 1.3 of the book [Gamma-convergence for Beginners](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=o_ickfZF3AMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA25) may help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2363351/), it helps to think in terms of epigraphs $\operatorname{ep} f = \{(x,y)\colon y\ge f(x)\}$. Epiconvergence is precisely the [Kuratowski convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence) of epigraphs. The epi-convergence $f_k\to f$ can be visualized as:

- every point   $p\in \operatorname{ep}f$ is being approached by the epigraphs $\operatorname{ep} f_k$ in the sense that $\operatorname{dist}(p, \operatorname{ep}f_k)\to 0$
- every other point $p\notin \operatorname{ep}f$ stays away from  the epigraphs $\operatorname{ep} f_k$ in the sense that $\liminf \operatorname{dist}(p, \operatorname{ep}f_k) > 0$.

The simplest example is the constant sequence $f_1=f_2=\dots$. The Kuratowski limit is then simply the closure of the set, so $\operatorname{ep} f  =\overline{\operatorname{ep}f_1}$, which means $f$ is the *lower semicontinuous regularization* of $f_1$.

For a nontrivial example, consider $f_k(x)=-\exp(-kx^2)$. The epigraphs are the upper half-plane with a narrow downward bump attached near $0$. The width of this bump tends to zero, and in the limit it becomes the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,-1)$. We get the epigraph of the function $f$ such that $f(0)=-1$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Also consider $f_k(x)= \exp(-kx^2)$. Now the epigraphs consist the upper half-plane with a narrow upward cavity near $0$. The width of the cavity tends to zero, and in the limit it *disappears*.  We get the epigraph of the constant function $f\equiv 0$.

The Kuratowski limit is always closed, so the epi-limit is always a lower semicontinuous function.

Finally, $f_n(x) = (-1)^n \exp(-nx^2)$ is a sequence that fails to epi-converge: the lower and upper Kuratowski limits are different.