# Why epi-convergence implies lower semicontinuity of the limit function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, convex-analysis

Here is the definition of epi-convergence in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epi-convergence). I was wondering if there exist functions $f_k$ such that $f_k$ epi-converges to $f$, then can we conclude that $f$ is lower semicontinuous?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (and that same Wikipedia page says so). As the name suggests, it's best to think about epiconvergence in terms of epigraphs $\operatorname{ep} f = \{(x,y)\colon y\ge f(x)\}$. The following facts are easy to check:

1. A function is lower semicontinuous if and only if its epigraph is closed.
2. The epigraph of epi-limit $f$ consists precisely of the limits $\lim (x_\nu, y_\nu)$ of all convergent sequences such that $(x_\nu,y_\nu)\in \operatorname{ep} f_\nu$.
3. The set described in item 2 is closed. (Think about the proof that the set of all subsequential limits of a sequence is closed.)

Note that this means that the epi-limit of a *constant sequence* $g,g,g,g,\dots$ is not necessarily $g$. For example, let $g(0)=1$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise. Then the sequence $(g,g,\dots)$ epi-converges to the constant function $f(x)\equiv 0$.